# Plotting dates on the x-axis and customizing labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I am trying to make a graph of a time series, but I'm having trouble achieving my desired result.
I have data from a time series from May 2021 to December 2022. Original data is by day, but for my visualization, months will suffice. I used `lubridate::floor_date()` and summarised the observations. The resulting data is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("2021-05-01","2021-06-01","2021-07-01","2021-08-01","2021-09-01","2021-10-01","2021-11-01","2021-12-01","2022-01-01","2022-02-01","2022-03-01","2022-04-01","2022-05-01","2022-06-01","2022-07-01","2022-08-01","2022-09-01","2022-10-01","2022-11-01","2022-12-01"),
                 n = c(30,44,58,49,52,40,31,21,29,17,25,14,20,17,10,11,7,20,5,4)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Date = lubridate::ymd(Date))

ggplot2::ggplot(data=df,
       aes(x=Date,
           y=n)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: Plot1]

The resulting plot is alright, and I like that it omits the days by default. However, I want the x-axis tick labels to start at 2021-05 and end at 2022-12, so I looked into `scale_x_continuous` and thought I'd play around, starting from displaying 20 ticks (one for each month in my time series) with `n.breaks = 20` and go from there. The result somehow botched the labels, so I am out of ideas.

[image: Plot2]

Eventually, I would like to assign custom labels using the `labels` argument inside `scale_x_continuous` to have my labels say "May 2021" or "December 2022".

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to set your desired breaks via the `breaks` argument . In the code below I used a sequence by 3 month intervals but you could set them to your liking. Also I formatted the dates to your desired format using the `labels` argument:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data = df,
  aes(
    x = Date,
    y = n
  )
) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-05-01"), as.Date("2022-12-01"), by = "3 month"),
    labels = ~ format(.x, "%B %Y")
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** Wasn't able to find an out-of-the-box-solution. But one option would be to set the locale:

```r
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")

lct
#> [1] "de_DE.UTF-8"

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "fr_FR")
#> [1] "fr_FR"

ggplot(
  data = df,
  aes(
    x = Date,
    y = n
  )
) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq.Date(as.Date("2021-05-01"), as.Date("2022-12-01"), by = "3 month"),
    labels = ~ format.Date(.x, "%B %Y")
  )
```

[image]

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
#> [1] "de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Comment: That is a nice solution, thank you very much! I see that your labels are German and in long form. I suppose that is due to your locale? Suppose I would like to have the labels spelt French (like "Décembre 2022"), how would I go about that without changing my language in R?

Comment: Good question. Just did some research for an out-of-the-box option to set the locale used for date formatting but wasn't able to find one. Hence the only option I could come up with is to switch the locale. see my edit.

Comment: Thank you again. Two things remain: 1) I can't get the long month names displayed like in your plots. I understand that those are stored in the built-in variables `month.abb` and `month.name` but I don't get how I can choose which to display. 2) I cannot get the December 2022 to show in the axis, although that's rather important. In fact, only three labels are important: May 2021, January 2022, and December 2022.

Comment: Hi Klaus. If you just want the three important dates you could do `breaks = as.Date(c("2021-05-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-12-01"))`. Of course could also combine this which `seq`, e.g. `breaks = c(as.Date("2021-05-01"), seq.Date(as.Date("2021-09-01"), as.Date("2022-12-01"), by = "3 month"))` to show the May and a tick for all 3 months staring with September. For the labels. I just saw that my first code included a typo. To get the abbreviated names use `format(.x, "%b %Y")`, for the full names use `format(.x, "%B %Y")`.

Comment: Thanks! Now we're getting into the really nitty gritty stuff. I really like the manual breaks but the problem with this approach and the other suggestion that the remaining automatically introduced vertical grid lines don't always align with a month/data point ... I think I will suppress those altogether. Thanks again!